# Encoding: certain characters coming back wrecked through cURL request?

Tags: php, caching, curl, encoding, rss

I have a PHP-powered RSS feed caching system. If a feed contains certain characters, e.g. curly quotes/apostrophes, these are coming back in the cURL response wrecked.

Example feed: http://www.theguardian.com/football/hullcity/rss (note curly apostrophes)

cURL code:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => CURL_CONNECT_TIMEOUT
));
```

Resultant data (extract from):

```
Sergio AgÃ¼ero is firing again, JosÃ© Mourinhoâ€™s propaganda ...
```

Is there some cURL option I should be configuring, or do I have no choice but to string-handle these out after cURL has finished?

I know there's a cURL option `CURLOPT_ENCODING` but to my knowledge that's about encoding data sent, not retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with encoding in feeds is *hard*. You have first to identify which encoding the text of the feed uses and then convert it to whatever encoding you want to display it with.

To determine the encoding, you have 2 looks in 2 different places:

- HTTP headers
- XML declaration

[Feedparser's documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/character-encoding.html) is the most explicit on how to deal with this. You could also use services like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) which will handle the conversion to UTF-8 for you!

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I'll just string-handle the nasties out myself and do the replacements manually... it's only a couple of recurrent symbols.